# Understanding of Aldon iSeries CMS

Tags: version-control, ibm-midrange

I have been trying to learn about Aldon, a CMS used on iSeries, from it's user guide and want to confirm if my understanding on this is correct.

I have understood that Aldon can be configured to have different environments like Staging, Development etc. apart from a Production environment. All these environments exist on the same iSeries server and have different libraries corresponding to these. An objects (consider a *PGM object) source , is checked out into the development library of the developer when a standard check out is done. Once the modifications on the checked out object are done, it can be promoted back to the upper environments.

This is where I want to know if what I understood is right - ***When the promotion happens, you can push the objects to the library that corresponds to an upper environment and optionally, you can ship it to a remote server that corresponds to the environment (for eg. Staging)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'answer' essentially is "Yes, that's right." Seems a little trivial, though. Also, even though that's a fairly basic setup, there is much more that might involved depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Promotion creates or changes the object at the next level.  Where ever that may be.